# Errors occur in simple calculator programs using bisonc++ and flexc++

Tags: c++, lang, bisonc++, flexc++

The following error occurs in the following program
I have looked at the flexc++ and bisonc++ references and think I understand some of it, but I have not been able to put together working code because the actual samples are not within my ability to search.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me where and how to modify the code to make it work.

flexc++ code

```
%%
"+"     return Parser::ADD;
"-"     return Parser::SUB;
"*"     return Parser::MUL;
"/"     return Parser::DIV;
"\n"    return Parser::NL;
"("     return Parser::BB;
")"     return Parser::BE;

([1-9][0-9]*)|0|([0-9]+\.[0-9]*) return Parser::NUM;

[ \t] //ignore;

. {
    std::cerr << "lexical error\n";
    exit(1);
}
%%
```

bisonc++ code

```
%polymorphic value: double;

%type <value> expr
%token <value> NUM
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV BB BE NL
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%expect 16

%start program

%%
program     : statement
                | program statement
                ;

statement       : expr NL
                    {
                        std::cout << $1 << std::endl;
                    }
                ;

expr            : NUM
                | BB expr BE
                    {
                        $$ = $2;
                    }
                | expr ADD expr
                    {
                        $$ = $1 + $3;
                    }
                | expr SUB expr
                    {
                        $$ = $1 - $3;
                    }
                | expr MUL expr
                    {
                        $$ = $1 * $3;
                    }
                | expr DIV expr
                    {
                        if ($3 != 0)
                        {
                            $$ = $1 / $3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            std::cerr << "division by zero" << std::endl;
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                ;
```

compile command

```
g++ *.cc -o main
```

error code

```
lexer: In member function ‘int Scanner::executeAction_(size_t)’:
lexer:2:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    2 | "+"             return Parser::ADD;
      |                               ^~~~~ 
lexer:3:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    3 | "-"             return Parser::SUB;
      |                               ^~~~~ 
lexer:4:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    4 | "*"             return Parser::MUL;
      |                               ^~~~~ 
lexer:5:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    5 | "/"             return Parser::DIV;
      |                               ^~~~~ 
lexer:6:23: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    6 | "\n"    return Parser::NL;
      |                       ^~~~  
lexer:7:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    7 | "("             return Parser::BB;
      |                               ^~~~  
lexer:8:31: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
    8 | ")"             return Parser::BE;
      |                               ^~~~  
lexer:10:20: error: ‘Parser’ has not been declared
   10 | ([1-9][0-9]*)|0|([0-9]+\.[0-9]*) return Parser::NUM;
      |                    ^~~~~~
In file included from parse.cc:6:
Parser.ih: In member function ‘int Parser::lex()’:
Parser.ih:17:12: error: ‘d_scanner’ was not declared in this scope
   17 |     return d_scanner.lex();
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
```

Hopefully we will have a simple quadrature machine, I tried writing it in flex or bison and including Parser.h in the C declarations section, but it didn't work with syntax errors.

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: Who is `Parser`? Did you define it?

Comment: "I tried writing it in flex or bison and including Parser.h in the C declarations section, but it didn't work with syntax errors." What was your plan when you tried it without including Parser.h? Did you expect it to work? How? If not, why are you showing us that code, instead of the version that does include Parser.h, and errors associated with that version?

Comment: @zdf Parser is generated from the bison script

Comment: Not used this particular flavour of bison before but `#include "Parser.h"` seems like the right choice, so I agree with the comment above, show us that version and the errors you get with that.

Comment: The [documentation](https://fbb-git.github.io/bisoncpp/manual/bisonc++03.html#l10) states that one of the outputs of bisonc++ is `A baseclass header, which can be included by lexical scanners (see below), primarily defining the lexical tokens that the parser expects the lexical scanner to return;`. So that seems to be the answer if you can identify what the baseclass header is (I wasn't able to).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I only want to do bisonc++ and flexc++, not bison or flex. That's why I didn't list the versions written in bison or flex.

Comment: OK but how did you plan for flex++ to know what Parser is?